# How to decrease a column in a table automatically when data is added in another table SQL

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables a "IN SHOP" table which has a variable "How many games in shop", no primary keys and 2 foreign keys of "Shop" where the primary key is ID and "Game" where the primary key is also ID.

Now I have a table "Purchase" which has a primary key of ID and foreign keys of "Shop ID" and "Game ID". Now I want to know if there is a way to automatically update the "IN SHOP" table variable "how many games" for every purchase. So if there is a new purchase the amount of games decreases by 1 and if a sale gets deleted the amount increases by 1.

I tried

```
alter table "IN SHOP"
   add constraint "FK_IN SHOP_REFERENCE_Purchase" 
       foreign key ("GAME ID") references TEHING ("GAMES ID")
       on update "HMGIS" = "HMGIS" -1
       on delete "HMGIS" = "HMGIS" +1;
```

Comment: Take a look at triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a trigger that you can use to update the amount in case of an insert or a delete action.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateAmount ON Purchase
FOR INSERT,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
    -- I am an insert
    UPDATE IN_SHOP
    SET HMGIS = HMGIS-1; -- use the count of the rows in inserted table for bulk insert
    END
   ELSE
    BEGIN
    -- I am a delete
    UPDATE IN_SHOP
    SET HMGIS = HMGIS+1; -- use the count of the rows in deleted table for bulk delete
    END
END
```

This is a question where it is explained how to determine if the trigger is fired by insert or delete: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137862/check-if-the-trigger-was-fired-by-insert-or-delete?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa.

Comment: This serves as example but careful with the amount of rows. In this example you will be decreasing 1 with 1 new purchase or 100.

Comment: Useful link regarding triggers that handle multiple rows of data https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers-to-handle-multiple-rows-of-data?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Okay, so I basically get what you are doing however I have a constraint but that would do it for every field in "HMGIS" I would like to do it for one specific game in story so should I add a WHERE sentence in there somewhere? so that it knows that the IN_SHOP game is the same as in the PURCHASE game

Comment: Update IN_SHOP
    Set Amount = Amount-(select count(*) from inserted ii where ii.Name = S.Name)
    FROM IN_SHOP S join inserted I on I.Name= S.Name   and on the delete case you do the join with deleted